# Need to sort array of object by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, underscore.js

I have an array of object and I need to sort each object by its key.

```
//original array of objects 

[ { "week1" : "10", "week2": "20", "week3" : "23"},
  {"week2" : "40", "week1", "30", "week3" : "24'}];

//expected resultant array

[ { "week1" : "10", "week2": "20", "week3" : "23"},
  { "week1" : "30", "week2": "40", "week3" : "24"}];
```

I want to achieve result using either JavaScript function or using any underscore.js function.

Comment: you can not sort the object's keys.

Comment: why would you need this in the first place?